# Algorithm Spacetime Tradeoff

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

We know that algorithms have a certain space and time complexity when implemented. Optimizing algorithms often involves a space-time tradeoff, where one increases space used in exchange for a decrease in time.

However, based on conservation of energy, and the equivalence of spacetime, are space-time tradeoffs in any way related? The energy saved by reducing runtime is instead spent in holding more items in memory, for example. (I know it's possible to have a bad algorithm that increases space and time always, but I am talking in the context of optimization.

Is there any way we can quantify this based on mathematical formulae?

Comment: If you are asking how a space-time trafeoff affects energy consumption, then you need an energy model for computation to do this. My guess is that in most cases the energy consumption will change as you traverse the tradeoff, it will not stay constant. Conservation of energy is a principle for physical systems, not computations.

Comment: Talking about analyzing space-time tradeoffs algorithmically, my guess is that it depends on the problem, or at least class of problems (say [for SAT](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/832/space-time-tradeoff-lower-bounds)). In general though, it's somewhat of an open problem (e.g. [see here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4556/space-time-tradeoff-and-the-best-algorithm))